# How can I create a mask on an HTML Object?

Tags: html, css, mask, image-gallery

I have seen in the apple site their big-images gallery in this link (for example):

http://www.apple.com/imac/

What attracted my eyes was that they sort-of masked these images so they will not be displayed outside the gallery box. In flash/as3 it is quite simple to mask an object - but how did they do it in the web?

How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's often done by making the image the background of a div. This div has hidden overflow, and the background image is centered in it. Within the div theres a img element which is a transparant png that can be used as the mask.

Comment: Actually, if you look at their source code, the images put in place using the IMG tag, inside of an HTML 5 FIGURE element.  Then they're using JavaScript to slide the FIGUREs into place using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

The gallery consists of one wide page with all the images in it, positioned with regard to the gallery's parent element.  The parent element has `overflow: hidden` set on it, so that the bits which extend beyond the edges are cut off.  To advance it, they have some JavaScript which slides the gallery one direction, bringing new areas into view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a div with an `overflow:hidden` property.

More info (unrelated):

If you want to add more complex mask you can use absolute div floating over your gallery, with a transparent png background. This will create flash like masking e.g. a png that fades out to white, so when scrolling through the gallery items it will create a cool effect. (this is a very simple example)